# How should logical quantifiers be understood if the domain of discourse is not specified?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, notation, quantifiers

Let $P$ be a predicate. The expression $\forall x:P(x)$ seems to have two different meanings, depending on the context:

1. If the domain of discourse $D$ is clear from context, then the statement "$\forall x:P(x)$" should actually be read as an abbreviation of "$\forall x\in D:P(x)$". For instance, in real analysis the statement $\forall x:x^2\ge0$ would be understood as an abbreviation of $\forall x\in\mathbb R:x^2\ge0$.
2. In set theory, it seems that $\forall x:P(x)$ means "for *any* set $x$, $P(x)$ is true". For instance, the axiom of extensionality is written as $\forall x:\forall y:\forall z:(z\in x\iff z\in y)\implies x=y$.

I don't fully understand the meaning of $\forall x:P(x)$ in the context of set theory. Naïvely, the statement $\forall x:P(x)$ seems to be an abbreviation of $\forall x\in \mathbf{U}:P(x)$, where $\mathbf{U}$ is the universal set. However, the "universal set" is not actually a meaningful concept in standard formulations of set theory, and so this interpretation is clearly wrong. So how should the statement $\forall x:P(x)$ actually be interpreted?

Comment: What problem is there with an unrestricted quantification that wouldn't be there with restricted quantification? Within the limits of this kind of interpretation, $\forall x: P(x)$ means that $P(y)$ is true for all objects $y$, just like $\forall x\in S: P(x)$ means that $P(y)$ is true for all objects in $S$, i.e. that $\neg (y\in S)\lor P(y)$ is true of all objects.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path: When we write $\forall x\in D: P(x)$, this statement has a clear enough meaning as "if you set $x$ to anything in $D$, then $P(x)$ is true". When we write, $\forall x:P(x)$ without specifying the domain of discourse, we seem to be tacitly assuming that there is a "universal set".

Comment: @Joe Actually, $\forall x \in D(P(x))$ is an abbreviation of $\forall x(x\in D\to P(x))$, so you have the same problem.

Comment: The membership symbol, $\in$, has a formal definition. Definition under which, as you say, the "universal set" does not exist. Let's just dispense with that here. Your interpretation correct: $\forall x P(x)$ means "for any set $x$, $P(x)$" is true. In an informal setting, you just accept that as part of the metalanguage of the subject at hand. In a formal setting, like in mathematical logic, those symbols are part of the language and basically are devoided of meaning. An expression like $\forall x\left(P(x)\right)$ is legal by virtue of the rules of formation of expressions.

Comment: You wrote that in set theory $\forall x : P(x)$ means "for any set $x$, $P(x)$ is true". This is correct, so why does it not answer your own question?

Comment: @GitGud: So, even in a formal setting, the symbol $\forall$ is not given a definition—it is just a "primitive symbol", similar to how "set" is a primitive notion in set theory. Is that correct?

Comment: @Joe That's right. You start with a bunch of symbols, among which the logical connectives, the quantifiers, variables (and others) and then some rules are defined that say "a well-formed formula is an expression built from the following set of rules": <set of rules>, and that's that. You, as a human, and because you know mathematics, and also because these formal systems were created to mimic mathematics in practice, can attribute meaning to it.

Comment: @GitGud: Thank you very much; that answers my question completely. You can convert your comments into an answer, if you wish to do so. But of course you are not obliged to!

Comment: @Joe See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_formula#Predicate_logic), for example.

Comment: If you don't mind, I'll wait a day or two before converting them to an answer as I'm interested in seeing how other people may approach this. You can then choose what answer you think is best.

Comment: @GitGud: Sure, no problem!

Comment: @Adayah: I think that *does* answer my question, but I was worried that by writing $\forall x:P(x)$, we were implicitly quantifying over the "universal set", which is non-sensical. You and Git Gud's comments have cleared upon my confusion.

Comment: @GitGud: Now I think of it, I think I my confusion might have occurred because in the somewhat similar notation $\{x:P(x)\}$, the domain of discourse *does* have to be clear from context. It cannot literally be understood to mean "the set of sets $x$ satisfying $P(x)$", as otherwise we are at risk of allowing Russell's paradox. Is that correct?

Comment: The semantics of first-order logic is parametrized by a putative set giving the universe of discourse and a putative interpretation of the non-logical symbol as members of , $n$-ary relations $n$ or $n$-place functions on that set. The definition of the semantics is carried out in a [metatheory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metatheory) that is not to be confused with the object theory (even though they could be the same theory). ZF set theory is no different from PA or any other first-order theory in this respect.

Comment: @Joe Right. People who care for such details wouldn't even write such "sets". The [axiom schema of specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification) basically tells you that you need something like $\{x \in A\colon P(x)\}$, you can't do without the $\in A$ part, for some set $A$.

Comment: $\forall x Px$ is interpreted differently in different interpretations... In the domain of naturals with "x is Even" as meaning for Px we have..., while in the domain of humans with "x is a Philosopher" as meaning of Px we have... So the issue is: what is a "suitable" domain of an interpretation for axiomatic set theory? See e.g. [Von Neumann universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_universe).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question in the title is. . .

> How should logical quantifiers be understood if the domain of discourse is not specified?

And the answer is that you don't understand them unless they're specified. It's possible the domain of discourse is clear from context, but that has much more to do human communication than with the mathematical content.

In the context of set theory, the domain of discourse is that of all sets.

This brings to light the following apparent issue.

> Naïvely, the statement $\forall x:P(x)$ seems to be an abbreviation of $\forall x\in \mathbf{U}:P(x)$, where $\mathbf{U}$ is the universal set. However, the "universal set" is not actually a meaningful concept in standard formulations of set theory, and so this interpretation is clearly wrong.

And the question. . .

> So how should the statement $\forall x:P(x)$ actually be interpreted?

As mentioned in the comments, your interpretation "for *any* set $x$, $P(x)$ is true" is correct. And this fine (or at least as fine as it can be). In this setting, the quantifiers are not formal entities. They're part of the metalanguage, just like English. We just enrinch the natural language (in this case English) with some extra symbols to facilitate communication. The $\in$ symbol is different, however, because in set theory it has a formal meaning.

There are contexts (e.g. [predicate calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_formula#Predicate_logic)) in which the quantifiers are formal symbols, in which they're not part of the metalanguage. In these contexts, the quantifiers are part of formal language just as much as $\in$ is in set theory. There are also formation rules that determine what formulas are legal, and in such systems a formula like $\forall x P(x)$ (it can be a little bit different, it may require some more parentheses, but it's something like this) is legal and that's that.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, there is nothing wrong with understanding "$∀x ( Q(x) )$" in a foundational set theory to mean "$∀x{∈}U\ ( \ Q(x) \ )$" where $U$ is the type of all objects (i.e. $U$ denotes the entire intended domain). $U$ does not have to be a set. In pure ZFC, $U$ is not an object, because otherwise we get a contradiction. $U$ is commonly called a **class**. In extensions of ZFC that can reason about classes *as objects*, such as NBG or MK, we have two sorts, one for "sets" and one for "classes", and $U$ is still not a set, even though it is now an object.

Typically "$∀x{\in}S\ ( \ Q(x) \ )$" can be treated as a short-form for "$∀x\ ( \ x∈S ⇒ Q(x) \ )$", and "$x∈U$" simply reduces to "true". Note that the "$\in$" here does **not** require any set theory in a strict sense, because $S$ can just be a sort (in many-sorted FOL). However, it is convenient to use the same symbol as for set membership because there is no danger of ambiguity. After all, in NBG and MK we literally have $E ∈ \{ t : Q(t) \} ⇔ Q(E)$ where "$\{ t : Q(t) \}$" is the class notation.

In fact, this usage of quantifying over classes is extremely common in higher set theory, such as "$∀k{∈}ORD$" where $ORD$ is the class of ordinals, which is (as explained above) perfectly fine even in pure ZFC.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It helps to get a different perspective.

Comment: @Joe: You're welcome!